# Can I add multiple properties to a string object by separating them with commas?

Tags: jquery

I don't know much about js and I would like to know if this is correct :

```
 anim = new anim(
    {
      boxClass:     'originalclassname, h2, #id-name .classname',   
      animateClass: 'animated', 
      offset:       0          
    }
  )
```

Original code

```
anim = new anim(
    {
      boxClass:     'originalclassname',   
      animateClass: 'animated', 
      offset:       0          
    }
  )
```

Edit : Here is the original library
[wow.js](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/blob/master/dist/wow.js)

Can I add other classes by separating them with commas? Also should I put the # in front of the idname and the dot in front of the classname as in the original it doesn't have one or should I add one to the existing? And can I put a class inside an id like this?

It works but I wanted to check that it's the correct syntax.

Comment: Please elaborate. what library(besides jQuery) do you use? it is very heard to help you, when you provide no info. I'm sure in couple of minutes, you will get vote-down and link to "how to ask questions in stackoverflow"

Comment: No clue what plugin you are using but it appears it wants a class name without the dot. h2 and #id-name are not classes.

Comment: In your code you have to pass an object, that is must be key+value formatted, not key+multiple-comma-separated-values. It is not depends on the jQuery plugin, it is vanilla JS. Regarding the use of ID or Class, reading the FAQ of the plugin will help you for sure.

Comment: And, as JonnieJS said, it is a bad formatted question.

Comment: @GiacomoPaita it is not comma separated values. it is one value, a string. Whether that string is supposed to be one class name or if it can be comma separated class names is completely up to the plugin's code.

Comment: Ok sorry, the library is wow.js [link](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/blob/master/dist/wow.js). @Brian does it mean I can only use classes?

Comment: Also if it works is it valid? Cheers!

Comment: From reading the code it is expecting a single class. It looks like you can trick it though by doing it like this: 'class1, .class2, .class3' (leave the dot off the first but add it to the rest)

Comment: @Brian Thank you that helps, but here the h2 works to; does that mean I can use it? or is it better to put a class instead?